# How Can I Make Sonar Ignore Errors In Return Types From Libraries?

Tags: java, sonarqube

One of the [Sonar rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1149) states:

```
Synchronized classes Vector, Hashtable, Stack and StringBuffer should not be used
```

and it marks all usages as a Major Code Smell.

In my project these are return types from a third party library I am using so I can't avoid using them when calling the API.

How can I make Sonar ignore the calls made to third party libraries and only report my own usages of creating these types?

Comment: Try adding `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1149")` on the icky method call!  S1149 appears to be the related rule, but that specific rule ID should be listed somewhere...

Comment: An alternative to suppressing the warnings in Sonar could be to use interface types when assigning the return values: `java.util.List`, `java.util.Map`, etc. This might not be as easy to do with `StringBuffer` (you would need to choose between `Appendable` or `CharSequence`, depending on the usage) and `Stack` (which doesn't actually implement its equivalent interface `Dequeue`) but those are less common as return types. If possible, the benefit is that your code would be less coupled to the specific return types of that library, and easier to change to another implementation in the future.